# Get rootPoject.name, or reference to settings.gradle, of included builds

Tags: gradle, groovy, include

I'm using `includeBuild` to include modules from my own library in `settings.gradle`:

```
rootProject.name = "MyApp"
include ':app'

includeBuild '/usr/local/library/Android/Event'
includeBuild '/usr/local/library/Android/Location'
includeBuild '/usr/local/library/Android/Widget'
```

I know I can iterate these later with:

```
gradle.includedBuilds.each{ includeBuild ->
    println includeBuild.name
}
```

However, that prints:

```
Event
Location
Widget
```

Is there a simple way to get the `rootProject.name`s that I have defined in each of those individual library projects' `settings.gradle` files?

I know I can do the following to give alternative names:

```
includeBuild('/usr/local/library/Android/Event', {name = 'com.example.android.event'})
includeBuild('/usr/local/library/Android/Location', {name = 'com.example.android.location'})
includeBuild('/usr/local/library/Android/Widget', {name = 'com.example.android.widget'})
```

... but that is redundant and cumbersome when I've already defined those as `rootProject.name` is their respective `settings.gradle`.

Rather, I'm looking for something akin to:

```
gradle.includedBuilds.each{ includeBuild ->
    println includeBuild.rootProject.name
}
```

For instance, I know about `includeBuild.projectDir`. Can I somehow get a (parsed) reference to the `settings.gradle` file in that directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve it using `org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnector`:

```
import org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnector
import org.gradle.tooling.ProjectConnection
import org.gradle.tooling.model.GradleProject

def getIncludedProjectNamesMap(Project project) {
    def projectNamesMap = new HashMap<String, String>()
    project.gradle.includedBuilds.each { includedBuild ->
        ProjectConnection connection = GradleConnector.newConnector()
                .forProjectDirectory(includedBuild.projectDir)
                .connect()
        GradleProject includedProject = connection.getModel(GradleProject.class);
        def name = includedProject.getName();
        connection.close();

        projectNamesMap.put includedBuild.name, name;
    }

    return projectNamesMap
}

println getIncludedProjectNamesMap(project)
```

... which prints:

```
{Event=com.example.android.event, Location=com.example.android.location, Widget=com.example.android.widget}
```

... but that appears to be rather slow, probably due to all the connections it need to make. It does the job for now, but I'm still looking for alternative approaches, if available.